# Как присвоить value после автозаполнения?

Tags: javascript

```
function checkItAll() {
var elements=document.querySelectorAll("#sampleform div.all");Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements,function(el,i){el.style.display='none';});
if(document.getElementById('level').value==""){$(".all").show(); $(".entry").hide(); $('.post').addClass('inactive') }
if(document.getElementById('level').value==1){$(".all").hide(); $("#level1").show(); $("#entry1").show(); $('.post').removeClass('inactive')}
if(document.getElementById('level').value==2){$(".all").hide(); $("#level2").show(); $("#entry2").show(); $('.post').removeClass('inactive')}
if(document.getElementById('level').value==3){$(".all").hide(); $("#level3").show(); $("#entry3").show(); $('.post').removeClass('inactive')}
if(document.getElementById('level').value==4){$(".all").hide(); $("#level4").show(); $("#entry4").show(); $('.post').removeClass('inactive')}
if(document.getElementById('level').value==5){$(".all").hide();     $("#level5").show(); $("#entry5").show(); $('.post').removeClass('inactive')}
if(document.getElementById('level').value=="фраза для автозаполнения"){$(".all").hide(); $("#level1").show(); $("#entry1").show(); $('.post').removeClass('inactive')}
}

function searchLevel() {
 document.querySelector("input").oninput = checkItAll;
}
```

Автокомлит:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 var wordForSearch=["фраза для автозаполнения"];

 $("#level").autocomplete({select: checkItAll,source: wordForSearch});
 });
```

Html:

```
<form action="" method="get">
<input onclick="searchLevel()" class="inputTypeText inputTypeText"   type="text" value="" size=57 id="level" placeholder="быстрая навигация по  уровням и лекциям, просто введите тут слово">
<input class="resetStyle" id="resets" type="reset" value="СБРОС" /><br><br> </form>
<div id="noResult"><span class="red_text"></span></div>
<input class="hideAndShowStyle" type="button" id="hide" value="Свернуть все"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class="hideAndShowStyle" type="button" id="show"  value="Развернуть все" />
<div id="content">
 <div class="all" id="level0">  
  <div class="post inactive"> 
   <div class="title"> 
   <h3>заголовок</h3>  
   </div>
    <div class="entry" id="entry0" style="display:none;">
     <p><a href="#" title=""><font size="3"></font></a></p>
      </div>  
     </div>
    </div>
 <div class="all" id="level1">  
  <div class="post inactive"> 
   <div class="title"> 
   <h3>заголовок</h3>  
   </div> 
    <div class="entry" id="entry1" style="display:none;">
     <p><a href="#" title=""><font size="3"></font></a></p>
     </div>  
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

*Обновлённый ответ.*

Нужно, чтобы ваша ф-я, которая исполняется по событию `input`, также выполнялась при автозаполнении. Для этого:

1) объявить её отдельно:

```
function checkItAll() {
    var elements=document.querySelectorAll("#sampleform div.all")
    ...
}
```

2) указать её как обработчик события `input`:

```
function searchLevel() {
    document.querySelector("input").oninput = checkItAll;
}
```

3) указать её и в параметрах для `autocomplete` как обработчик события `select`:

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
    select: checkItAll,
    source: wordForSearch,
    minLength:2
});
```

P.s. в самой ф-ии не городите сто раз `document.getElementById('level').value`, а лучше используйте конструкцию `switch .. case`:

```
switch( document.getElementById('level').value) {
    case 1:
        $(".all").hide();
        $("#level1").show();
        $("#entry1").show();
        $('.post').removeClass('inactive');
        break;
    case 2:
        ...
```

Comment: инпут вызывает функцию, которая проверяет условия.. и если значение поля search = 1,2,3 и т.д.. раскрываются определенные блоки div. Но помимо цифр, необходимо искать слова и выводить определенный блок.. Все работает если вводить в поле вручную, если же выбрать вариант из автокомлита, то поле не принимает значение и условие не выполняется... сейчас добавлю код.

Comment: А, ну так у вас конфликт: событие изменения поля обрабатывает и плагин `autocomplete` и ваша функция. У плагина есть свой API, и, в частности, вызывается событие [`select`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select), когда выбран предложенный вариант. Вероятно, вам надо зацепиться и там с собственными проверками.

Comment: как-то можно решить проблему?

Comment: изменил код, но все равно не работает.. где-то что-то не так делаю... Насчет свитч понятно..